# Can't show information from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an application in rails and I'm trying to use a column  type_id in relationship with my other table

My tables:

**sinisters**

```
+---+----------+---------+
|id | client   | type_id |
+---+----------+---------+
| 1 | Charles  |       1 |
| 2 | Montalvo |       1 |
| 3 | Gabriel  |       2 |
| 4 | Miguel   |       2 |
+---+----------+---------+
```

**sinister_types**

```
+----+--------+   
| id | name   |
+----+--------+ 
|  1 | DANGER |
|  2 | FIRE   |
+----+--------+
```

My controller:

```
@sinisters = Sinister.find(:all)
```

My models:

```
class Sinister < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sinister_type
end

class SinisterType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sinisters
end
```

My view:

```
<% @sinisters.each |sinister| do %>
   <%= sinister.client %>
   <%= sinister.type.name %>
<% end %>
```

I want to show sinister types names.

I tried this code and got nothing:

```
<%= sinister.sinister_type.name %>
```

And also tried and got nothing

```
<%= sinister.type.try(:name) %>
```

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @backpackerhh says, the default convention is `sinister_type_id`, not `type_id`. But if you want to override it, you need to specify `:foreign_key`.

**Model :**

```
class Sinister < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sinister_type, :foreign_key => :type_id
end

class SinisterType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sinisters
end
```

**Controller :**

```
@sinisters = Sinister.find(:all)
```

**View :**

Not `@sinisters.each |sinister| do`, but `@sinisters.each do |sinister|`

```
<% @sinisters.each do |sinister| %>
   <%= sinister.client %> :
   <%= sinister.sinister_type.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your column on `sinister` table should be `sinister_type_id` (instead of `type_id`) or you need to specify the foreign key on your model.